# How to Shrink and Restore Divs in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a website to help out a relative, but am new to web development and have little experience. Right now, I am have a few divs that I want to manipulate as you scroll down, and undo the changes as you scroll up. The issue I am facing is that the divs change (shrink/slide/etc) properly after the scroll bar crosses a certain point, but if you go back up to the top, nothing happens, so the animations only run once. ".animate" is the only event that's giving me an issue, while the remaining events work flawlessly. Here is a copy of my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Sarah's Portfolio</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="navigationbar.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="image">
            <img src="Project Images\\Sarah.png" id="Sarah">            
        </div>
        <div id="name">
            <h1>Sarah James</h1>
            <h2 id="objective">OBJECTIVE</h2>
        </div>
        <table id="navbar" cellspacing=0>
            <tr>
                <td><u><i><a href="index.html">Home</a></u><i></td>
                <td><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></td>
                <td><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></td>
                <td><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="topbar"></div>
        <div id="rotatingblock" align="middle">
            <img width=90% height=50% class="mySlides" src="Project Images\\AsburyPoolComplex\\page-4-1.jpg">
            <img width=90% height=50% class="mySlides" src="Project Images\\AsburyPoolComplex\\page-5-1.jpg">
            <img width=90% height=50% class="mySlides" src="Project Images\\AsburyPoolComplex\\page-6-1.jpg">
        <script src="rotationblock.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var $scroll=$(window).scrollTop();
        if ($scroll>60){
            console.log ("bigger than 40 and is " + $scroll);
            $("#name").animate({top:"2%",height:"13%",left:"35%"},500);
            $("#image").animate({width:"8%",left:"5%",top:"3%"},500);
            $("#navbar").animate({top:"-17%"},500);
            $("#topbar").animate({height:"25%"},500);
            $("#objective").html("<h2></h2>");
            $("td").animate({height:"20%"},500);
            $("a").css("font-size","150%");
        }
        else{
            console.log ("smaller than 40 and is " + $scroll);
            $("#name").animate({height:"21.5%",left:"40%"},500);
            $("#image").animate({width:"15%",left:"0%",top:"2%"},500);
            $("#navbar").animate({top:"1.3%"},500);
            $("#topbar").animate({height:"43%"},500);
            $("#objective").html("OBJECTIVE");
            $("td").animate({height:"20%"},500);
            $("a").css("font-size","175%");
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to the method you have right now try replacing the numbers you have at the end of your animate functions with explicit declarations as to which options you're targeting, so that you can add more options and do:

```
{ duration: whateverMilisecs, queue: false }
```

so

```
$("td").animate({height:"20%"},{ duration: 500, queue: false });
```

However, it might just be easier for you to use CSS transitions.

Add a .anim class to whatever objects you want to animate with these options:

```
.anim{
  -webkit-transition: all 1s; // Chrome
  -moz-transition: all 1s; // Mozilla
  -o-transition: all 1s; // Opera
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

and this class is the option you want to animate:

```
.doThingy{
  transform: translate( 0px, -500px); 
}
```

Then within your if statements do:

```
if(etcetc)
  $(target).addClass('doThingy');
} else {        
  $(target).removeClass('doThingy);
}
```

Basically you use CSS to tell the browser that that element will animate. Then you add and remove classes when necessary, which will trigger the animations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, if I am not mistaken, the "queue:false" prevents the animation from running again, right? The thing is, I'd like the animation to keep occurring should it change. What I mean by this is, when you scroll down, the divs should be manipulated as per the statements inside the "if" statement; when you scroll up to the top, the divs should be manipulated as per the statements inside the "else" statement, so that you can keep going up and down and the animations keep occurring. Once again, thank you very much.

Comment: NP. It prevents the animation from having to wait after any other queued animations.

Comment: Ok, with a little bit of testing I finally got it to work. Thank you very much for your help. What ended up working was adding the "queue:false" statement to all of the ".animate" events. Once again, thank you very much.

Comment: Hey, no problem, buddy. :)